# What are the differences between 'CaseIterable' protocol's allCases and AllCases?

Tags: swift

I am curious about the differences between 'CaseIterable' protocol's `allCases` and `AllCases.` According to Apple's document:

`allCases` : A collection of all values of this type. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable/2994869-allcases

`AllCases` : A type that can represent a collection of all values of this type. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable/2994868-allcases,

The most common usage when using 'CaseIterable' protocol seems to be `allCases` and I am aware of its actual usage in enum, but I can't find a solid example that explains the usage of `AllCases`. Any input will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: As it says in the documentation, it’s a type (associatedtype) so you can use it to declare variables or parameters

Comment: Do you happen to know any of its usage in practice? Example?

Comment: Well it is used in the declaration of allCases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, go learn what [associated types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) are.

Armed with that knowledge, you'll understand that `AllCases` just has to be a `Collection` of instances of a type—not specifically the `Array` of *enumeration* instances you'll generally experience it expressed as.

So, for a type with enumerable instances, whose order doesn't matter, you could use a `Set`, for example.

```swift
extension Bool: CaseIterable {
  public static var allCases: Set<Self> { [true, false] }
}
```

```swift
extension Sequence where Element == Bool {
  var containsBothBools: Bool { Bool.allCases.isSubset(of: self) }
}
```

```swift
[true].containsBothBools // false
[false].containsBothBools // false
[true, false, true, true, false, true].containsBothBools // true
```

Comment: Thanks Jessy, a big fan of your work, I myself started studying Swift with your materials from rayWenderlich.com! Will be sure to study more on Associated types.